# Skyrim Add-ons and DLCS

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Is it possible to get add-on for the Xbox 360 besides Hearthfire, Dragonborn and Dawnguard and if so how?

Comment: Are you asking about mods?

Comment: No, since 1. There aren't any more DLC packs and 2. I don't think Modding is supported on the 360 (I could be wrong on 2.)

Answer (score 1):

You have all of the DLC if you have what you listed.

On consoles, mods are handled through the launcher/main menu for the game.  If you don't see something that lets you connect to Bethesda's mod service (the only one supported for console), you can't get them.   As I recall, Bethesda asserted a lack of mod support for 360 some time before Skyrim Special Edition came out.